# Knockout.js with jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, caching, knockout.js, tablesorter

I try to sort a table, generated from a Knockout.js template. The problem ist that jquery Tablesorter kind of caches all the tr's. I'm aware of tablesorters .trigger("update") but I don't know where to apply it. I tried "afterRender", custom bindings, e.t.c - without any results at all... I made a jsfiddle, maybe this clears things up: http://jsfiddle.net/a8jUj/1/

If you sort without setting some entries inactive, everything works. If you first set something inactive and then sort the table, it reappears?!

**Update:**
Ok, I fell in love with knockoutjs - AGAIN :) They have some neat utilities included, one of them has the ability to sort observableArrays -> http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort activeUsers using a [sort algoritm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp). The view will automatically update! You shouldn't interact with the view directly like

```
$("#list1").tablesorter();
```

But do somthing like this:

```
function sortUsers(a,b){
  return a.name() < b.name();
}

activeUsers.sort(sortUsers);
```

Comment: So, I'm confused. Your answer to how to use tablesorter with knockout is to not use tablesorter? I guess the OP is satisfied but what if you want to use tablesorter for it's other features (themes, widgets, grouping, etc.)? Is it just not compatible?